# sum of the series?

Tags: summation

let sum of the series

$$S=1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1........$$

$S=\frac{1}{2}$

my question is if there are even number of terms then the sum is $0$

and if the number of terms are odd then sum is $1$.

but we don't know whether its odd or even because the sequence goes to infinity.

Is the answer derived by using the probability of getting either $0$ or $1$

---

I am making an edit to this, can it done by using the 
where $i $ is 4th root of unity

1. $$S=i+i^2+i^3+i^4+i^5.....$$

$$S=i-1-i+1+i-1-i+1.....$$
then $1$ can be summed up using infinite sum of Gp
which is $$S=\frac{a}{1-r}=\frac{i}{1-i}$$
by simplifying we get $$S=\frac{i}{1-i}\frac{1+i}{1+i}=\frac{i-1}{2}$$
and take the real part of $S=Re \big[ \frac{i-1}{2}\big]=-\frac{1}{2}$

is it a wrong way to solve this problem ???

Comment: this series (infinite) has no sum

Comment: How do you define your sequence of points 1-1+..........

Comment: Look up Grandi's series.

Comment: This "series" has been considered by Euler. Have a look at the very interesting document (eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2006-06.pdf)

Comment: Sorry I should not use the proved statement @G.Sassatelli

Comment: The Cesaro sums tend to $\frac12$ but the series itself is divergent.

Comment: (ctd from @Henry) Otherwise said, it is convergent in the sense of Cesaro (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation). This convergence is known to be weaker (thus more "tolerant") that usual convergence.

Comment: @Boris I've updated my answer for your updated question.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is not "$1/2$", but rather it is regularized to give one half:

$$S=\lim_{x\ \uparrow\ 1}1-x+x^2-x^3+\dots=\frac12\\S=\eta(0)=\frac12\\S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}n=\frac12$$

where $\eta(z)$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) and $S_n$ is the $n$th partial sum.

Other methods also yield $1/2$, but you are dealing with a divergent series, so any ideas like grouping do not make sense.

---

Specifically concerning your solution, you should notice that the real part of your series is

$$-1+1-1+1-1+\dots$$

which is $-1$ times the normal result.  A more correct way to use your idea would be to take

$$S=\Re(\lim_{x\to i}1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots)$$

since the geometric series only works for $|x|<1$, we have to avoid the problem of convergence via limits.  Notice that you cannot apply the limit to each term individually, as you will get a divergent series.  Instead, you should calculate the series first, then take the limit, then the real part.

Comment: What is $\eta(0)$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie it is the dirichlet eta function.

Comment: Thanks. I was knowing the $\zeta$ function but not the $\eta$ function

Comment: @JeanMarie they are the same except one has alternating signs.

Comment: Jean's question is a hint that you should probably include a link to Dirichlet $\eta$ in your answer. OTOH, $\frac1{1-(-1)}$ (the geometric series) is more elementary.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Sorry, was on phone earlier, so rather hard to do.  Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: yes what i did is not valid

Answer (score 4):

Look this(Terence Tao-Analysis I):[image: enter image description here[1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9mRv.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I think its better to provide a link and summarize the passage here.

Comment: But isn't it beautiful @SimpleArt??

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Depends if you are on school wifi and all the images are blocked.  Then you can't see anything here.

Comment: ooh   :) :) :) :)

Comment: @Simple Art,I get it.Because I want to show more content directly, but in my mobile phone will be very inconvenient to edit them. Thank you for your suggestion, next time I will pay attention.

Comment: No problem.  Cheers for the good find too!

Answer (score 3):

That series is $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n}$$ whic has no sum because
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}(-1)^n\neq 0.$$

So, writing as $S=1-1+1-1+\dots$ is not allowed. Hope you are clarified.

Comment: why does summing $S=1-1+1-1+1-1.......$ ,$S=1-S$,$S=\frac{1}{2}$ ,is it not summation or its just letting that its equal to S

Comment: @Boris it has to exist first for that to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

This is called Grandi's series, you can see about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi's_series).

I think he defined it to be $0.5$ in some meaning the average of all its partial sums, is equal to $0.5$.

Comment: Please see [Cesàro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation)

Answer (score 2):

For $n\geq 0$, let $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k.$$

then

$$S_{2n}=1$$
$$S_{2n+1}=0$$

$\implies (S_n)$ is not convergent.
thus

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\notin \Bbb R$$.